# Re-using Drop Down List on Multiple Web Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, drop-down-menu

I am new to ASP.Net.

Is there a way the re-use drop down list and its behind code (below) on several web forms? Through using WCF?

(For Example : "Change Setting" in the drop down menu will redirect to the Setting page through Response.Redirect(""). )

Answer (score 0):

Reusing a drop down list and its behind code, you can use Asp.net [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984211%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). I am not familiar with WCF, but I get this post: 
[How to load a Web User Control inside a WCF service and returning the result?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1445506.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20flipcart%20like%20panel%20for%20showing%20products%20in%20gridview)
Hope it can help you.